# Android: Navigation drawer indication not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am following a tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zuo3n-DjF7w), but I'm stuck at (+/- 41 min).
I'm expected to see a indication when I click on a menu item, but this doesn't happen.
The picture below shows how it's supposed to look:

**how it should look:**
[image: Navigation drawer tutorial]
**Main Code:**

```
package com.example.flori.mylordring;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{


    private static ImageButton imgView;
    private int test;
    int [] images = {R.drawable.im1,R.drawable.im2,R.drawable.im3,R.drawable.im4,R.drawable.im5,R.drawable.im6,R.drawable.im7};
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView navList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        navList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navlist);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ArrayList<String> navArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        navArray.add("Home");
        navArray.add("Fragment 1");
        navArray.add("Fragment 2");
        navArray.add("Fragment 3");
        navArray.add("Fragment 4");
        navArray.add("Fragment 5");
        navList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,navArray);
        navList.setAdapter(adapter);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.opendrawer,R.string.closedrawer);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Rolololo", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle saveInstancesState){
        super.onPostCreate(saveInstancesState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }


    public void image(View view){
       imgView=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           test++;
                                           test = test % images.length;
                                           imgView.setImageResource(images[test]);
                                       }
                                   }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }else if(id == android.R.id.home){
            if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navList)){
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navList);
            }else{
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(navList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:

                break;
            case 1:

                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:

                break;
            case 5:

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

thank you in advance ;)

Comment: I think Your item selected state is not maintained while drawers are opened and closed.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` instead of `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` and implement this method:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        } else if (id == R.id.add_goal) {

        }
```

Implementing NavigationDrawer is easy with the latest version of Android Studio. Just create new Activity from File-New-Activity-Navigation Drawer Activity.

[Here is a good tutorial with the latest Navigation View](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html)